# How do I synchronize NSScrollViews on Yosemite?

Tags: cocoa, osx-yosemite, nsscrollview

I followed the advice in the Scroll View Programming Guide to synchronize two NSScrollViews that contain NSOutlineViews. The left outline view has table headers but the right one does not. In OS 10.9 the table rows were aligned by making the left table 17 px higher and everything works fine. On  Yosemite the two tables are offset by what looks like 17 px. It seems that NSClipView.documentVisibleRect includes the header on 10.10 but does not include the header on 10.9.

Here is a screenshot of the app running on 10.10. You can see that the outline view on the right is scrolled down too far relative to the left outline view. On 10.9 they are aligned. [image: screenshot]

Comment: A screenshot would really help here.